# Textbook on the history of General Relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, history

I have studied General Relativity from various textbooks already, and the subject fascinated me immensely. I was wandering if there is any textbook that deals with the chronological "steps" that Einstein took (from 1906 to 1916) to complete his theory. I have read some passages from "The Collected Papers of Albert Einstein" and found them very interesting, especially all his correspondences with Tullio Levi-Civita. What I am looking for is something along the lines of this: https://www.pitt.edu/~jdnorton/teaching/HPS_0410/chapters/general_relativity_pathway/index.html
but in **much** greater mathematical detail. Is there any such textbook around?

Comment: As always, the [SE on the history of science](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) should be the first/simultaneous stop.